# How to display dates in my app without excessive load?

Tags: meteor, momentjs

In my application I have posts, and in my post page I'm showing posted date as `a minute ago` using `moment` package.

I'm displaying dates using the following code

```
Template.registerHelper("postedTime",function(date){
        return moment(date).fromNow();
 });
```

and in my HTML

```
{{#with post}}    
.............
............
{{postedTime date}}
............
............
{{/with}}
```

I know these dates are not reactive. In my post I have hundreds of comments also with the same date format.

What is the best way to update all those timings without much load to the client browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dates are not reactive by themselves, so you need to include a reactive data source in your helper to force it to rerun.

In this example, we'll update a session variable that will force all instances of `postedTime` to be reevaluated every 60 seconds:

```js
Template.registerHelper('postedTime', function(date) {
  Session.get('timeToRecompute');
  return moment(date).fromNow();
});

setInterval(function() {
  Session.set('timeToRecompute' new Date);
}, 60 * 1000);
```

Comment: With this, wherever I use `postedTime` they will automatically updated every minute? If so, is it too much load(or freeze ) for browser? or the browser can take these loads easily(suppose if I have 100 such time stamps)?

Comment: Yes, they will all be automatically updated. There should be no perceptible load. There is only one timer, so hundreds of instances `postedTime` should not be a problem.